# How to show the degree $[\Bbb Q(\alpha _n+\frac{1}{\alpha_n}) : \Bbb Q]$ is $\phi(n)/2$, where $\alpha_n$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity?

Tags: roots, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots, cyclotomic-polynomials, cyclotomic-fields

> How to show the degree $[\Bbb Q(\alpha _n+\frac{1}{\alpha_n}) : \Bbb Q]$ is $\phi(n)/2$, where $\alpha_n$ is a primitive $n$-th root of unity?

I already know that $[\Bbb Q(\alpha _n ):\Bbb Q]$ is Euler-phi function $\phi(n)$.  But, I have no clue what to do next? Is it possible to find the irreducible polynomial for $\alpha _n +\frac{1}{\alpha_n}$ over $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Do you need to find an irreducible polynomial to find the result? It isn't hard to do, but it is actually easier to prove that the degree is $\phi(n)/2$ by showing that $[\mathbb Q(\alpha_n):\mathbb Q(\alpha_n+1/\alpha_n)]$ is a divisor of $2$ and the fields are not equal...

Comment: Nope. It does  not need to find the poly. But why  [ℚ(αn):ℚ(αn+1/αn)] is a division of 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $k,\gcd(n,k)=1$ :
$$ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)= \mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi k/n))(i\sin(2\pi k/n))$$
$i \sin(2\pi k/n)$ is a root of $x^2+1-\cos^2(2\pi k/n)$ a polynomial of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi k/n))$ and so $$[ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n): \mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi k/n))] \le 2$$
Since it is real $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi k/n)) \ne \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ and : $$[ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n): \mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi k/n))] = 2, \qquad \phi(n) = [ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n): \mathbb{Q}] = [ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n): \mathbb{Q}(\cos(2 \pi k/n))][ \mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi k/n)): \mathbb{Q}]$$
$$[ \mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi k/n)): \mathbb{Q}] = \phi(n)/2$$

Comment: I think you mean $\cos(2k\pi/n)$? $\cos(nk)$ is a bit weird.

Comment: Oh, you are right. i have just encounter problem when I'm trying to proof this.

Comment: Tks for the typo. @JohnHsia $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n) = \mathbb{Q}(\cos 2\pi /n)(i)$ iff $4 | n$ (not even sure anymore, but when $4 \nmid n$ clearly they are different)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What different things ?

Comment: @user1952009 It's the first comment i leaved before, i have deleted it. It were wrong. I wrote $\Bbb Q$ is the splitting field of $x^2 +1$ over $\Bbb Q\ \subset\ \Bbb R$, but i'm actually mean that $\Bbb Q(ζ_n)$ is the splitting field of $x^2 +1$ over $\Bbb Q(cos(\frac{2\pi k}{n}))\ \subset\ \Bbb R$

Answer (score 1):

If you let $\beta_n=\alpha_n+\frac{1}{\alpha_n}$. Then, clearly $\mathbb Q(\beta_n)\subseteq \mathbb Q(\alpha_n)$, since $\beta_n=\mathbb Q(\alpha_n)$.

You first have to show it is a strict subfield - that $\mathbb Q(\alpha_n)\neq \mathbb Q(\beta_n)$. That can be seen by noting that $\beta_n$ is real, and $\alpha_n$ is not, for $n>2$.

An alternative approach is to show that the automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\alpha_n)$ sending $\alpha_n$ to $\alpha_n^{-1}$ fixes $\beta_n$ and thus all of $\mathbb Q(\beta_n)$, but does not fix $\alpha_n$ unless $n=2$.

But if $\alpha_n+\frac{1}{\alpha_n}=\beta_n$ then $x^2-\beta_nx +1$ has $\alpha_n$ as a root, so $\alpha_n$ is at most degree $2$ over $\mathbb Q(\beta_n)$.

So we get $$\phi(n)=[\mathbb Q(\alpha_n):\mathbb Q]=[\mathbb Q(\alpha_n):\mathbb Q(\beta_n)][\mathbb Q(\beta_n):\mathbb Q]=2[\mathbb Q(\beta_n):\mathbb Q]$$

The minimal polynomial for $\beta_n$ can be computed in terms of Chebyshev polynomials, but you have to deal with repeated roots and the like.